# How to report a bug in Office 365 Android SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk, office365

I was pointed at Stack Overflow by Microsoft support as the place to get help about the Office 365 Android SDK, including how to report bugs.

I'm finding that a call to Item.getDateTimeLastModified() will consistently return an incorrect date/time.  Most of the time, if an item has been recently updated, it will return a millisecond value (in the GMT time zone) that is anything up to 2 hours and a few minutes ahead of current GMT.

Other date times such as Event.getStart()/Event.getEnd() are returning the correct values.

When processing calendar events I am using the following to retrieve events:

```
ListenableFuture<List<Event>> eventsGet = this.userFetcher
                .getCalendar (this.calendarId)
                .getEvents ()
                .top (pageSize)
                .skip (skip)
                .select ("Id")
                .filter (modFromDate)
                .orderBy ("DateTimeLastModified")
                .read ();

List<Event> events = eventsGet.get (60,
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then I process the events one at a time and using the id get the actual event using:

```
this.userFetcher.getCalendar (this.calendarId).getEvent (id).read ().get (60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Calling getDateTimeLastModified on that event will return the strange value.

I can provide calendar/event ids if required.

As an aside, I notice that the Office.com calendar when it retrieves the json data for the event has the correct last modified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Anahí from the Office 365 SDK for Android team.

We've created an issue with your problem in our GitHub repository and will start reviewing it. We'll post the updates there once the error is fixed.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Android/issues/86

The GitHub repo is the best place to submit bugs/issues since we're reviewing it all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please make that clear on the github page then and also inform Microsoft support that.

Comment: Sure! We'll update the readme with that info. BTW, we could reproduce your error, we're working in the solution now.

Comment: @GaryBentley, we fixed the issue. It will be available in next release.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Android/issues/86

Answer (score 2):

You can submit bugs/issues on the Office 365 SDK for Android on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Android) where the project is hosted.

Comment: It seems that someone from github has taken this stack overflow posting and created an issue in github.  However, the important thing to note here is that Microsoft support themselves pointed me at stack overflow as the place to report bugs.  Microsoft, please sort this mess out.

Comment: Do you have a ticket number or the name of the person you spoke with? I can see what I can do to inform them. Thanks!